# General purpose DRM software

Tags: 3d, drm

I have studied the existing DRM (Digital Rights Management) products on the market and all I have found was related to books, images, audio or video content.

I need to protect 3D models with DRM. Does anyone know the more general-purpose DRM product that can work with various types of products, including digital 3D models?

Yes, I know that DRM is bad and security through obscurity does not work. But this is the requirement of the customer.
So any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to encrypt the file and sell the passcode or have a website where you can purchase models. Also what operating system do you want to run this on.

Comment: Let's say I want to have a website where I sell 3D models with textures.
I don't think operating system matters, I want it to work on all platforms.
Obviously I can develop my own 3D model format, encryption and try to hide the key somehow on the client. I just wanted to know if there are any existing solutions.

Comment: well you could use an existing website such as turbo squid or another site like that where you sell 3D models. If you need something self hosted why don't you just program something where you pay for access to a model download.